# Removing bitwise flags

Tags: c++

How would i remove flags from my enum

I can add them easy with `m_Buttons | (button);`

```
enum WindowButton
{
    None = 0,

    Minimize = (1 << 0),
    Maximize = (1 << 1),
    Close = (1 << 2),
};
inline WindowButton operator|(WindowButton a, WindowButton b)
{
    return static_cast<WindowButton>(static_cast<int>(a) | static_cast<int>(b));
}
inline WindowButton& operator |= (WindowButton& lhs, WindowButton rhs)
{
    return lhs = static_cast<WindowButton>(static_cast<WindowButton>(lhs) | static_cast<WindowButton>(rhs));
}
```

This is the function where im trying to add / remove

```
void Window::SetButton(WindowButton button, bool show)
{
    if (show)
        m_Buttons |= (button);
    else
        m_Buttons | ~(button); // This is not working to remove flags
}
```

Comment: Using `|` instead of `|=` means `m_Buttons` isn't going to be modified... but `|=` wouldn't be right either.

Comment: Hint: Turning a bitflag on `flags |= f`. Turning a bitflag off: `flags &= ~f`.

Answer (score 4):

> `m_Buttons | ~(button); // This is not working to remove flags`

Of course not. It sets where it should clear, and then throws away the result. Should be

```
m_Buttons &= ~button;
```

NB parentheses are redundant here.

Comment: '&=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type

Comment: @xuzisijuya So define `&=` the same way you defined `|=`, except using `&`.

Comment: @xuzisijuya (And I'd almost forget, `operator~` as well.)

Comment: @hvd still getting the same errors

Comment: Of type *what*? What type have you defined `m_buttons` as? Should be `int` or `long`.

Comment: @EJP `m_Buttons` is defined as `WindowButton`

Comment: @xuzisijuya Well that's wrong. WindowButton can only have the values enumerated within it. Or else *define* that operator, just as you've defined the others.